# "Shops cannot create Listings in languages other than the Shop's primary language. (fr)" Etsy Request Error

Tags: etsy

I'm using the Etsy2 module on Python to automatically create a listing using the createListing() API request, but unfortunately I always get the following error:

```
ValueError: Could not decode response from Etsy as JSON: status_code: 400, text: "Shops cannot create Listings in languages other than the Shop's primary language. (fr)", url 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings'
```

Is it possible to create a listing in my shop's language instead of English? The language=fr parameter is not supported for this request...
Thank you!